# Change Multiple (Including No) File Extensions

Tags: bash, shell, rename

If I have a directory of files, where some files have an extension like .html and some files have no extension, how do I change them all to, e.g. .txt?

Comment: This should be a good start: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1224786/297629

Comment: I looked at that, but didn't understand how to do .html and nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe this should work for you (probably more elegant ways to do this with sed).

```
for file in *; do
  base=`echo "${file%.*}"`
  mv -- "${file}" "${base}.txt"
done
```

Comment: @NoneHere I don't quite see why you need to `echo` and capture something in order to store it in a variable. Couldn't you just use `${file%.*}` directly as the base?

Comment: You are absolutely right John, the echo is unnecessary. Nice catch.

Comment: One other thought for you AdamG - bear in mind that these solutions do not have any error control so conflict situations such as having files named "test" "test.html" and "test.csv" will have the above try to rename them all to test.txt...

Answer (score 0):

To rename all of them in the shell would be something like this:

```
for file in *; do
  mv -- "${file}" "`basename -- "${file}"`.txt"
done
```

You may want to test the type with `file` or other checks to determine the extensions.

Comment: This does not work. It only appends .txt to the file. I need to change some extensions, and add to others.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily more elegant, but for completeness, here's a `sed` solution:

```
for file in *; do
  mv "$file" "$(echo "$file" | sed 's/^\(.*\)\.\?.*$/\1.txt/')"
done
```

The sed bit grabs everything before the last dot in the filename, and replaces the dot and whatever follows with '.txt'. If there is no dot in the filename, then '.txt' is just appended to the whole thing.

The quotes around the variables are important for handling filenames with spaces and such, regardless of which method you go with.